# Tkinter not exiting while Threading

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am making an updater for my application. There I used threading to update changes besides downloading files. But when I am trying to exit the code after all files get downloaded, it isn't!

Here is my code:

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import threading
import time
from google_drive_downloader import GoogleDriveDownloader as gdd

def updatenow():
    global ifexit
    print('Updating')
    #os.remove('myIDLE.exe')
    opening.configure(text= 'Downloading Package (1/1)')

    #gdd.download_file_from_google_drive(file_id='--', dest_path='./myIDLE.exe')
    #gdd.download_file_from_google_drive(file_id='--', dest_path='./get-files.exe')
    opening.configure(text='Installing Packages...')
    #os.system('"get-files.exe"')
    #os.remove('get-files.exe')
    time.sleep(2)
    #os.system('"myIDLE.exe"')
    winstart.destroy()
    exit()

def showlogo():
    global opening, winstart
    winstart = Tk()
    winstart.focus_set()
    winstart.overrideredirect(True)
    window_height = 512
    window_width = 1024
    screen_width = winstart.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = winstart.winfo_screenheight()
    x_cordinate = int((screen_width/2) - (window_width/2))
    y_cordinate = int((screen_height/2) - (window_height/2))
    winstart.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(window_width, window_height, x_cordinate, y_cordinate))
    winstart.resizable(0, 0)
    logo = PhotoImage(file='myIDLE Logo.png')
    logolable = Label(winstart, image = logo).pack()

    opening = Label(winstart, text='Preparing for Update...', font=('Helvetica', 14), bg="#1B1D2A", fg="#00A4A3")
    opening.place(x=5, y= 482)
    myt = threading.Thread(target=updatenow)
    myt.start()

    winstart.mainloop()

showlogo()
```

When I run this, the file gets downloaded, and `winstart` gets closed, but the program keeps on running.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What is `exit()` ?

Comment: @CoolCloud Its used to exit the program, maybe?

Comment: Maybe try `import sys` and then `sys.exit(0)`  instead of that?

Comment: @CoolCloud Still not exiting...

Comment: Maybe because both are in different thread? They cannot communicate with each other? Not sure.

Comment: @CoolCloud Is it because of Threading? Also how to end a thread?

Comment: If I could terminate the thread, the program would stop. How to end a thread?

Comment: Im not sure, let google be your friend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224770/discussion-between-samaksh-gupta-and-cool-cloud).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to my own problem. The problem was because of the thread which was still running even after destroying `winstart` (`root` window).

The problem was caused due to the following line:

```
myt = threading.Thread(target=updatenow)
```

Instead, if we write

```
myt = threading.Thread(target=updatenow, daemon=True)
```

when the main window is destroyed, the thread would stop.
And hence, the program would exit with code 0.